# How to change base url from https://www.example.sg/ from https://www.example.sg/aaa?

Tags: url

How to change base url from https://www.example.sg/  from https://www.example.sg/aaa?
I would like to permanently append "aaa" next to https://www.example.sg/. Usually, when I click, for example, "test" category, the base url is  https://www.example.sg/ and the url for "Test" category will be https://www.example.sg/test. What I would like to be right now is that the base url is https://www.example.sg/aaa and the url for "Test" category will be https://www.example.sg/aaa/test.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your base URL of the store by following any of the below methods

From the Admin Panel

```
System >> Configuration >> Generel >> Web
```

See the below screen shot

[image]

Or the another way is you can directly change it from the database using phpmyadmin changing its value in the table:

```
core_config_data
```

[image]

Or either you can change it using command line follow the below steps:

1 Log into the client's server using terminal

2 Gain access to MySQL using m or mysql -u root -p.

3 Access their database using the following command, where database is the database name.

```
use database
```

4 Run the following command:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

5. This will display the current base_urls set in Magento
6. To change the base URLs, execute the following commands:

   update core_config_data set value = '`http://domainname/aaa`' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data set value = '`http://domainname/aaa`' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

Your website base url will be changed now.

Comment: Hi, I did follow your way but it does not work and my website gone. Only html page is shown. Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: you have to clear the magento cache folder to make it work

Comment: My registered domain is https://www.example.sg/ but the url 'https://www.example.sg/aaa' what I want to change now has not been registered. but I am just appending aaa next to registered url https://www.example.sg/. My webpage is gone because of this?

Comment: You're missing some vital knowledge about domains and URLs to be even thinking about working with Magento. I highly suggest you familiarize yourself with it. The short version is that the domain that you have to register ends with the /. Anything you put after it is whatever you want it to be. I suspect your site is not working because both answers here tell you to add `aaa` to the url, while it should be `aaa/`. The base url MUST end with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to

```
System  >  configuration  >  General  >  Web
```

to change `Secure Url`.

Or you can go to database `core_config_data` , then replace url `https://www.example.sg/` to `https://www.example.sg/aaa`

Comment: Can I change even though I do not register https://www.example.sg/aaa? because I already registered https://www.example.sg/ and what I want to do is to append aaa next to the registered url https://www.example.sg/. Is it ok?