# Magento 1.9 change base url form http to https

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, https, base-url

I see **HTTP** mixed content found on my website.
I recently did https. This is my site

> https://www.legacyfurniture.net/

when i load i still see http  links for menu and base url.

I followed below steps still same.

> https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/change-baseurl-magento1/
>   and 
>   [How to change base url from https://www.example.sg/ from https://www.example.sg/aaa?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38428/how-to-change-base-url-from-https-www-example-sg-from-https-www-example-sg)

**Please help.**

Answer (score 1):

See table (core_config_data) in your database.

Search below paths under path column:

> (web/unsecure/base_url) and set Url without https.
>
> (web/secure/base_url) and set Url with https.

After that your website will work fine.

Comment: its works, in my setup

Comment: If i switch both to https the admin login doesnt work.  so i have kept unsecure url to http and secure to https. if you see in page source you will get base url still as http. even though i load site with https.

Comment: Ok so now its fine for you, have checked in that table "core_config_data"

Comment: its work for me!

Comment: Ok Thanks and Don't forget to accept this answer , it will help others

Comment: sorry its still not working. you can checkout my livesite url. when i load site in https its still showing base url in view source as http.